# C++: Error with Boost Filesystem copy_file

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm running into some trouble with the copy_file function. My program is very simple, I'm just attempting to copy a text file from one spot to another.

The following code brings up a "Debug Error!" because abort() was called.

```
int main()
{
path src_path = "C:\\src.txt";
path dst_path = "C:\\dst.txt";

cout << "src exists = " << exists( src_path ) << endl;  // Prints True
boost::filesystem::copy_file( src_path, dst_path );

return 0;
}
```

If I look at some other examples of code on Stackoverflow I cannot notice what I'm doing wrong. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

I have Boost v1.47 installed and I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: permissions or sharing violations. You should catch the exceptions and show them

Comment: I've looked up how to use try / catch but I'm unsure how or if I can print the exception without knowing the exception's data type. I can only catch it using the default (...) catch so far. I think filesystem raises an object called 'basic_filesystem_error', an object that isn't imported in my includes.

Comment: `try{/*code*/}catch(std::exception const& e){ std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; }` will do if the exception in question is derived from `std::exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the target file exists.

The [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html):

> ### <sub><sup>`template <class Path1, class Path2> void copy_file(const Path1& from_fp, const Path2& to_fp);`</sup></sub>
>
> **Requires**: `Path1::external_string_type` and  `Path2::external_string_type` are the same type.
>
> **Effects**: The contents and attributes of the file from_fp resolves to are copied to the file to_fp resolves to.
>   **Throws**: `basic_filesystem_error<Path>` if `from_fp.empty()` `||` `to_fp.empty()` `||` `!exists(from_fp)` `||` `!is_regular_file(from_fp)` `||` **`exists(to_fp)`**

A simple test like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::filesystem;
    path src_path = "test.in";
    path dst_path = "test.out";

    std::cout << "src exists = " << std::boolalpha << exists( src_path ) << std::endl;  // Prints true
    try
    {
        boost::filesystem::copy_file( src_path, dst_path );
    } catch (const boost::filesystem::filesystem_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
src exists = true
Error: boost::filesystem::copy_file: File exists: "test.in", "test.out"
```

on the second run :)

Comment: Ah-ha, you helped me figure it out. It was a two part problem. When I first tried the copy_file function it tried copying a file to a place where it already exists (your explanation). I then tried the code above which causes a permission error since apparently my settings disallow my program from copying files to the root path C:\

Comment: @akaGrim: That's good news (in a way, I deserve _two_ accepts then :) LOL). Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score -1):

I think if you are using boost::filesystem2 it should be 
    boost::filesystem2::copy(src_path,dest_path);
copy_file should have been deprecated.